# if cell(C2) l contains '@", remove the domain text + "@", else, output original value(C2) / check one cell against many string groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So there are two things i want to accomplish

1. I am trying to leave only the usernames in username@gmail.com
   I do not want to use the text splitter supported by excel as
   I want to use a condition.

Condition: if username contains '@', remove all the domain part.
If username does not contain '@' just leave the username as it is.

2. I want to check each username string (not by each letter, but as a word) to
   a list of words.

example) 'apple'[A1] checks against list of words containing the following words 'apple','dog','cherry'[B1:B3], and returns true, if 'apple' word in [A1], case sensitive, exists in the list[B1:B3].

I've already tried with https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-contains-one-of-many-things
but ended up with many incorrect values.

Here's the link to the google spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vqnUTfYdTGdOjHPotiZz-TZxCJl8HasRfKohm6S20Q/edit#gid=1069521208

feel free to edit it!

Thanks for your help!

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r7W3.png)

Comment: Text-to-Columns, Delimited, Uncheck everything but Other and use @, Next, Select 2nd column and Do not import column, Finish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeeped, Is there a way to use 'LEFT(D2,FIND("@", D2) - 1) ' with the IF conditions? thanks. I was looking to use the excel functions to resolve this problem. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: Text2Cols doesn't require another column; it can change everything in place or put the changes somewhere else. Your choice. A formula demands an unused column to fill in as a 'helper' column. Personally, I'd use `=iferror(replace(c2, find("@", c2), len(c2), text(,)), c2)`

Comment: Oh thanks now it works. How about the second part of the question. could you help me with that?

Comment: The 'second part' is not at all clear. You want to 'check each username string ... to a list of words'. And then 'returns true if ... exists in the list'. Returns true where? Countif beside the word in the list? Put TRUE in another helper column? It really isn't clear what you want to do beyond generalities.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any further information. That is not appropriate for comments.

Comment: for your second problem you may want to use `countif`. If `countif(range, username)` is > 0

Comment: @Jeeped Hey I've edited the question so it's more clear now. I want to check a single word, 'apple' in A1, and to the list containing many words. I want another column to return 'TRUE' if A1 exists in the list. If you need further clarification, let me know! thanks so much